# No menu item "OAuth", can't paste provider values into client

Tags: cv, oauth

Following the steps in https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/oauth/

After the installation of the OAuth2 extension, I don't get an "OAuth" item in the menu
"Administer => System Settings => OAuth"
There is an "Authentication" item, but it points to authx, not to OAuth.

So, I am not getting the CiviCRM page where I can paste the "Client ID" and "Client Secret" values into the client.

How to continue? Can I get the page using cv?

-- CiviCRM 5.59.3 on DRUPAL

Comment: have you tried rebuilding your menus?

Comment: @kapn, yes, i always do

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. I've not run into things not appearing on menus even after a rebuild. I would personally try uninstalling and re-installing the extension, but maybe you've tried that too.

Comment: @kapn yes i tried un-/re-installing too.

Comment: @kapn do you know the link that is called up in the menu item?

Comment: https://civi.sitename.to/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Foauth @markDQ

Comment: @kapn, thx, but I'm using Drupal as CMS, the URL is different

Answer (score 1):

For backdrop the url is : website.com/civicrm/admin/oauth

I had the same issue, no Oauth menu, but we have a staging version of the site which is showing the Oauth menu item -- so I used that to get a working url (above).

But I got an access denied error. I asked my co-worker to log in and see if that's what they got too -- which is what they got it; they then reminded me that the permissions are not set for roles/users for Oauth -- so I set the permissions and that seemed to have worked: website.com/admin/config/people/permissions

Again this is for backdrop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Agree that if a menu item is missing for something that has been recently added/enabled (or just used/noticed for the first time) then go check the CMS permissions